# items stored in memory with 8G RAM, bad alloc at memory location

Tags: visual-c++, heap-memory

I ran into a memory problem recently and I am very new to this, so hope someone can give me some pointers.

---

- RAM: 8G
- CPU: i7

---

Pop up Window shows that

Unhandled exception at 0x759fc41f in ParticleSystemJames.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0017ec78..

---

Stack Trace in VS2010 Debug Mode:

```
KernelBase.dll!759fc41f()   
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]    
KernelBase.dll!759fc41f()   
msvcr100d.dll!_unlock(int locknum)  Line 375    C
msvcr100d.dll!_unlockexit()  Line 785 + 0x7 bytes   C
msvcr100d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo)  Line 157   C++
msvcr100d.dll!operator new(unsigned int size)  Line 64  C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!std::_Allocate<SpringLink *>(unsigned int _Count, SpringLink * * __formal)  Line 36 + 0x15 bytes    C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!std::allocator<SpringLink *>::allocate(unsigned int _Count)  Line 187 + 0xb bytes   C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!std::deque<SpringLink,std::allocator<SpringLink> >::_Growmap(unsigned int _Count)  Line 1599 + 0x15 bytes   C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!std::deque<SpringLink,std::allocator<SpringLink> >::push_back(const SpringLink & _Val)  Line 1265 + 0x34 bytes  C++>    
ParticleSystemJames.exe!ParticleSystem::createLink(Particle * p1_ptr, Particle * p2_ptr, _Material material)  Line 128  C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!createVoxel(int p_x_idx, int p_y_idx, int p_z_idx, _Material p_material, double p_voxelEdgeLen)  Line 358   C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!addPoints()  Line 226 + 0x4f bytes  C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!runSimulation()  Line 654   C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)  Line 708 C++
ParticleSystemJames.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x19 bytes  C
ParticleSystemJames.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 371  C
kernel32.dll!752133aa()     
ntdll.dll!776d9ef2()    
ntdll.dll!776d9ec5()
```

---

Code (L below is a std::deque (not vector with pretty good reason), and the following function will be repetitively called more than 200,000 times):

```
SpringLink* ParticleSystem::createLink(Particle* p1_ptr, 
Particle* p2_ptr, Material material)
{

bool isDirectlyLinked = this->isDirectNeighor(*p1_ptr, *p2_ptr);

// Create the Spring Link
SpringLink* springLinkPtr = new SpringLink(p1_ptr->getIdx(), p2_ptr->getIdx());     
springLinkPtr->addMaterial(material);
springLinkPtr->isDiagonal = !isDirectlyLinked; 
L.push_back(*springLinkPtr);
int linkIdx = L.size()-1;
L[linkIdx].setIdx(linkIdx);

// Fill in the 'neighorhood' info  
p1_ptr->addNeigParticleIdx(p2_ptr->getIdx(), linkIdx);
p2_ptr->addNeigParticleIdx(p1_ptr->getIdx(), linkIdx);

// Create the link display - for drawing only
SpringLinkDisplay* springForcePtr = new SpringLinkDisplay(p1_ptr, p2_ptr);
//springForcePtr->k = springLinkPtr->k;
// For drawing different material using differet colors
springForcePtr->set_colorRGBA(springLinkPtr->get_colorRGBA());
// For drawing diagonal link using differet colors
springForcePtr->isDiagonal = !isDirectlyLinked; 
S.push_back(*springForcePtr);
int forceIdx = S.size()-1;
S[forceIdx].setIdx(forceIdx);

return &(L[linkIdx]);

}
```

---

Questions:

- is there a way in VS2010 Ultimate that I can monitor the heap usage quite conveniently without running profiling?
- I opened the 4 windows under Debug -> Windows -> Memory, but have no idea how we can use it here to help locate this kind of memo access violation, any one has any ideas?
- is there any other realistically good free heap/memo monitor for Win 7 that can help with this situation?

---

EDIT:

I just found something that might be interesting, in my task manager monitor

--Phycial Memory (MB)--

Total 8183

Cached 2599

Available 2544

**Free 4**

--Kernel Memory (MB)--

Paged 274

Nonpaged 250

-- Questions: --

- But then isn't Available is the only figure that matters?
- So even my 'Free' figure is reduced to close to zero as my application runs, but that's just used for 'front loading' libraries and not the cause of my exception, isn't?
- If it is the 'Free' part that caused the problem, what is the best approach to resolve this besides of optimizing my code significantly?

Comment: It does not look like you have an access violation but an out of memory failure. Check the debugger Output window for more info. Double clicking on the stack display will take you to code, where you can examine variables.  What is the 'size' being passed to new, what is the _Count being passed to _Alloctate?  Is this a 32-bit app? If so you can only get about 2 GB total, even with 8 GB physical memory.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP thanks for the advice! So say if it is a 32 bit app, then is there a way and a tool that I can use to affirmatively say and visually see when these 2GB heap size is used up/overflowed?